# OpenCart - добавить больше символов в название товара в корзине

Tags: opencart

Может знаете где в базе данных находится название товаров ( которые отображаются в корзине )

В файле cart добавил желаемое:

```
echo mb_substr( $product['name'],0,300,'utf-8' )."...";
```

- но получается только сократить. Где-то в базе данных стоит ограничение на кол-во символов.

Искал в базе в таких таблицах: _product и _order_product , находил поле name - менял на TEXT, менял varchar на 500 - результат ноль. В чём причина? Куда копать? Где искать?

**OpenCart:** 2.3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Советую посмотреть контроллер и представление, где выводится конкретно эта корзина. Не исключена вероятность "костыля", который в определенных выводах уменьшает количество символов типа "для верстки"

Comment: Может знаете название этого контроллера?

Comment: зависит от того, где это выводится. Корзина в опенкарте как правило не имеет своего виджета, и класс cart используют в различных контроллерах и темплейтах, посмотрите контроллер и темплейт common/footer

Comment: Там таких классов, что на скриншоте нет. Но я ведь уже нашёл в каком файле выводится - cart.tpl, но почему-то добавив mb_substrt - нет никакого эффекта, кроме как, сокращение.`<a class="cart-name" href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo mb_substr( $product['name'],0,500 ); ?></a>` Удалив этот код - название убирается.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема крылась в этом файле:
/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/common/cart.php
**Поправил эту переменную:**
    $option_data[] = array(

```
     'name'  => $option['name'],

     'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value),

     'type'  => $option['type']

    );
```

Вопрос решён.